# React Material UI and useKeenSLider - How to get array of value of <Slider/>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have  from MUI and useKeenSlider, i need to get array of values of every  of useKeenSlider

here are my code:

```
 const [sliderValues, setSliderValues] = useState([]);

 const handleSliderChange = (event, value) => {
    const updatedValues = [...sliderValues];
    updatedValues[currentSlide] = value;
    setSliderValues(updatedValues);
  };

   <Slider
          size="small"
          marks={marks}
          onChangeCommitted={handleSliderChange}
          defaultValue={3}
          aria-label="Small"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
/>
```

i have tried to pass  number and array to useState, but this dosen't work(